# react-router-dom i want to render the page for each element from map

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Hello i have a problem with react-router-dom i set up this route in App.js ```

````
 and i want for eaxh element from my map to go to that Singleitem component and take all the params that elements have this elements is from an api i let down my code ``` 
    <div className="wrapper">
                    {this.context.dailyShop.map((item, idx) => (
                        <div key={idx} className="itemCard">
                            <div className="itemtest">
                                <p className="textName text">{item.item.name}</p>
                                <p className="textCost text">{item.store.cost}</p>
                                <Link to={"/single/:" + item.item.name}>
                                    <img className="itemPhoto" src={item.item.images.background} alt="alt" />
                                </Link>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </div>
````

and here is the singlepage component ```import React from 'react';

const Singleitem = ({ match }) => {
console.log(match)

```
return (
    <div>
        hello from single page item {match.params.name}
    </div>
)
```

}

export default Singleitem ```

i only get in that component the name and i want more props like id and more

Comment: shortly what i need is to send all params to that component not just the name

Comment: i want to send all the data to params not only the name how can i make that

Comment: i made it thanks man